# Obtain full path of desktop using plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, desktop, spool

I'm trying to obtain the full path of the server's desktop using a plsql script. running the script on the server itself.

There seems to be no methods inside plsql to retrieve it. I need to spool the output of my script to the desktop no matter on which computer/server. So the username and desktop path can be different on other machines.

EDIT:
Currently trying:
dbms_system.get_env('userprofile', desktop);

I can get the path of the desktop but it is not the current user's one. What i get is C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Desktop

Also have tried:
SQL> host echo %username%

Administrator

Ultimately the path i need is i.e. C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop
but the username cannot be hardcoded...

Comment: Given that Oracle server runs on many platforms it seems unlikely that it will have a method to determine a specific path on a specific platform.

Comment: Thanks Rene, what you said is very true.

So I've decided to use a .bat file instead, since I'm doing it on windows. I simply navigated to the desktop and run sqlplus. It will automatically spool to the desktop! :)

>echo off 
>cd %userprofile%\desktop 
>sqlplus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally a server can't write directly to a client's desktop / filesystem. The client software requests a stream of data from the server and then the client may write it to the screen, a file....

If the client software isn't being co-operative, I'd look at emailing the results to the user.

[You can get the OS_USER and IP of the client using SYS_CONTEXT and USERENV, but that probably isn't useful, and definitely not if they have come through an app-server.]

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the info. I'm running the script on the server itself and want to display the output on the server's desktop.